# How to overload + operator so can write newVacation = oldVacation + 5, // which adds 5 to numDays, while just copying numPeople

Tags: c++, overloading

I am trying to write a program that overloads the + operator. When I input 7 and 3, it correctly prints:
First vacation: Days: 7, People: 3
But incorrectly prints:
Second vacation: Days: -158458720, People: 32764
It should be outputting:
Second vacation: Days: 12, People: 3

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class FamilyVacation {
 public:
  void  SetNumDays(int dayCount);
  void  SetNumPeople(int peopleCount);
  void  Print() const;
  FamilyVacation operator+(int moreDays);
 private:
  int   numDays;
  int   numPeople;
};

void FamilyVacation::SetNumDays(int dayCount) {
numDays = dayCount;
}

void FamilyVacation::SetNumPeople(int peopleCount) {
numPeople = peopleCount;
}

// FIXME: Overload + operator so can write newVacation = oldVacation + 5,
//        which adds 5 to numDays, while just copying numPeople.

FamilyVacation FamilyVacation::operator+(int moreDays) {
numDays = moreDays + 5;  
}


void FamilyVacation::Print() const {
cout << "Days: " << numDays << ", People: " << numPeople << endl;
}

 int main() {
 FamilyVacation firstVacation;
 FamilyVacation secondVacation;
 int userDays;
 int userPeople;

 cin >> userDays;
 cin >> userPeople;

 cout << "First vacation: ";
 firstVacation.SetNumDays(userDays);
 firstVacation.SetNumPeople(userPeople);
 firstVacation.Print();

 cout << "Second vacation: ";
 secondVacation = firstVacation + 5;
 secondVacation.Print();

  return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operator has **undefined behavior**.

It is declared as returning a new `FamilyVacation` object, but is actually not returning anything at all. That is why `secondVacation.Print()` is printing garbage.

Worse, your operator is modifying the object it is being called on (and not even modifying it with the *correct* value!), which is the wrong behavior for this operator to implement. See [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Try this instead:

```
FamilyVacation FamilyVacation::operator+(int moreDays)
{
    FamilyVacation ret;
    ret.SetNumDays(numDays + moreDays);
    ret.SetNumPeople(numPeople);
    return ret;
}
```